# Python Poetry is installed but 'poetry : The term 'poetry' is not recognized' Windows Powershell

Tags: powershell, python-poetry

I have installed Poetry version 1.4.2

When I run

```
(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://install.python-poetry.org -UseBasicParsing).Content | python
```

I get

```
The latest version (1.4.2) is already installed.
```

However, when I run `poetry --version` I am getting

```
poetry : The term 'poetry' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ poetry
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (poetry:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I am a beginner and not sure on whether I should be adding the PATH environment variable to "System Variable" or "User Variable" so I have added the following to PATH for both system and user:
`%APPDATA%\pypoetry\venv\Scripts\poetry` and `%APPDATA%\Python\Scripts`

Neither work, and I still obtain the same error.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your use of `python` as the Python executable suggests that you're using a Microsoft Store / `winget`-installed Python version, in which case `poetry.exe` ends up in a different, non-obvious location under `$env:LOCALAPPDATA` rather than `$env:APPDATA`. If so, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76084029/45375).