# Unrecognized command after poetry's installation on Windows 11

Tags: windows, powershell, python-poetry, microsoft-store

I never had troubles with the official installation of Poetry on Ubuntu systems. Now I'm trying to install it on Windows 11 in which there is Python 3.10. I've used the Power Shell commando as explaned [here](https://python-poetry.org/docs/#installation):

```
(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://install.python-poetry.org -UseBasicParsing).Content | python -
```

After that I've checked poetry:

```
poetry --version
```

> - poetry --version
> - ```
>   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (poetry:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>   ```

On JetBrains' [site](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/poetry.html#84a89960) there is a guide to install poetry and I've used the command below at the end of installation:

```
$Env:Path += ";C:\Users\massi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Scripts"; setx PATH "$Env:Path"
```

But nothing is changed. Any suggestions?

Comment: [Asked many times already](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=poetry+powershell). [Latest just a few days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76061812). Also this kind of question is barely in scope for StackOverflow, it is a Q&A website, not a personalized support website.

Comment: Error says Command not found (not cmdlet not found).  So script is looking for the command using the PATH environmental variable or expect the command to be in the same folder as the parent command.  So solution is to modify the PATH variable or put command in same folder as the parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your post-installation attempt to both update the in-process `Path` environment variable as well as its persistent definition, via `setx.exe`, the implication is that **the `poetry.exe` executable is *not* located in `C:\Users\massi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Scripts`**, despite what the [installation instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/poetry.html#84a89960) state, which is indeed the case:

- The fact that you're **piping to `python` rather than to `py` implies** that **you're using a Microsoft Store / `winget`-installed version of Python**.
- This version **effectively *redirects* to a different, non-obvious location in the `$env:LOCALAPPDATA` directory subtree** (*not* under `$env:APPDATA`, as the official instruction state) during the installation:

  - Its *ultimate* location is hinted at in what the installation process outputs, under `Actual location`.
  - One option is therefore to try to *parse* this output in order to glean the relevant location, but it's simpler to **discover the true location of `poetry.exe` after the fact** - see below.

```
# Discover the true location of poetry.exe, via $env:LOCALAPPDATA
$actualDir = 
  (
    Get-ChildItem $env:LOCALAPPDATA -Recurse -Filter poetry.exe -ErrorAction Ignore
  ).FullName[-1] | Split-Path

# Add it to the in-process copy of the Path environment variable
$env:Path += ";$actualDir"

# This should now succeed.
poetry --version
```

As for ***persistently* updating the `Path` environment variable**:

- Note that **`setx Path "$env:Path;$actualDir"` is best avoided** for persistent updates to the `Path` environment variable(s): while it *may* have no (immediate) ill effects, it *can*:
  `setx.exe` has a hard 1024-character limit, and invariably replaces the original `REG_EXPAND_SZ` value with a `REG_SZ` value, which means
  that basing entries on *other* environment variables no longer works. Additionally, you're *duplicating* entries by basing your new value on `$env:Path`, which is a *composite* of the system-level and the user-level definition.
  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69239861/45375) for more information, which also offers a **custom `Add-Path` function for *robust, side effect-free* updating**.
- If you want to **update the persistent `Path` definition *manually***, run `$actualDir | Set-Clipboard` in order to copy the directory path to the clipboard, then run `sysdm.cpl`, click on the `Advanced` tab, button `Environment Variables...`, and add the path on the clipboard to either the *user*-level or the *system*-level definition of `Path` (the latter requires administrative privileges).

Comment: Many thanks @mklement0 I've appreciate your useful support