# Windows: Poetry isn't recognized and commands aren't working although it has already been installed properly

Tags: python, python-poetry

poetry : The term 'poetry' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- poetry install
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (poetry:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

I tried with the poetry documentation to install again and it says that the latest version is installed. But whenever I try running commands like poetry shell, poetry install, etc. it gives me an error.

Comment: Is Python's "Scripts" folder on your `PATH` environment variable? Try entering `echo %path% | find /i "Python311\Scripts"` on the command line (you should replace `311` with whatever your current python version is). If you get any output from that command, it means your problem may lie elsewhere, but if it's blank then that could be the issue!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently. When doing the windows installation, Poetry has installed its 'poetry.exe' within `"AppData\Roaming\Python\Scripts"` which was not my python folder !

So, I move this 'poetry.exe' into the correct one `"\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts"` and it worked.

Hope that helps,

**EDIT:**

A proper and more pragmatic solution (inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/76086485/5763115). In powershell (or cmd):

> run sysdm.cpl, click on the Advanced tab, button Environment Variables...

and add the path = "%appdata%\Python\Scripts" in the variable Path.

It worked for me.